# oracle JET Combobox(dropdown) value does not disappear on populating empty array

Tags: knockout.js, oracle-jet

[Screenshots of dropdowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdIsG.png)I'm using Oracle JET combobox and dynamically assigning values to it on change of some event. 
When an empty array is assigned to the dropdown, it still shows the old selected value(As shown in image 4) .

Below is the code i've written:
 HTML:

```
<oj-select-one id="id1"  options="[[newDropDown1]]" 
options-keys.label="name" options-keys.value="value" 
on-value-changed="[[myOnChange]]"  value="">   </oj-select-one>

<oj-select-one id="id2" options="[[newDropDown]]"  
options-keys.label="name" options-keys.value="value"      
value=""  placeholder="select .."></oj-select-one>
```

JS:

```
self.newDropDown1 =ko.observableArray([{name:'Chrome',value:1},
                                    {name:'Opera' ,value:0},
                                    {name:'Firefox' ,value:2}]);

self.newDropDown =ko.observableArray([{name:'Yes',value:1},
                                    {name:'No' ,value:0}]);

self.myOnChange = function() {
              self.newDropDown([]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind its value to an observable like `self.newDropDownValue`.

On change event handler set it to empty `self.newDropDownValue("")`.

If you don't want to use a separate variable then you can use `reset()` method of the component.

```
document.getElementById('id2').reset();
```

The above method will erase the user entered values. See below link

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.ojComboboxOne.html#reset

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem myself. I found a workaround, but have not investigated why it works, however, it does.

1. Bind the `<oj-select-one>` element's `value` attribute to an `observableArray`. Even though it is not an `<oj-select-many>` element, still, use an array.
2. When resetting, set the value to an empty array, like so: `self.value([])`.
3. Make sure your `<oj-select-one>` element has a `placeholder` attribute, otherwise, this will not work.

I am pretty sure that this behavior is not intentional, but it does the job for me.

Comment: I have tried this and it will create a "blank" option. Behavior should be, it should not create any option at all.

Comment: You could make your `<oj-select-one>` element `disabled` then. Create a custom logic, where you tie a boolean value to the length of your options array, so for example:
`selectDisabled = () => self.value().length`
Then bind your element's `disabled` attribute to that:
`<oj-select-one disabled="[[selectDisabled()]]">`